# Wifi 6 improvements cause less interference using 40mhz in 2.4?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

My router usually sets automatically my Wi-Fi 2.4 in any channel using 40mhz bandwidth. It has wifi6 in both bands.

I know people says that in 2.4 the 20mhz is recommended. But apparently my WiFi signal is stronger with 40mhz in this WiFi 6 router.

I didn’t find anything about it on the internet, but, I was wondering, wifi6 in 2.4 help it to has less interference even using 40mhz bandwidth? Or the same idea to use 20mhz in 2.4 is still valid in WiFi 6 too?

Answer (score 2):

Recommendation hasn't changed.

There is really no 40MHz bandwidth. The bandwidth of all Wi-Fi channels is 20MHz. Wide bandwidths (40MHz & 80MHz) are achieved with bonding 2 and 4 adjacent channels together. Why it's not recommended on 2.4GHz range is simply the lack of available channels.

Interference comes in 2 varieties; Wi-Fi and non-Wi-Fi. The congestion in 2.4GHz range caused taking 5GHz channels in use in the first place. A lot of devices work on this range, starting from wireless mouses and keyboards. The interference on this range is mostly due to co-channel interference and adjacent channel bleed.

5GHz signal doesn't carry as far as 2.4GHz signal. Consequently on this range interference is mostly coming from non-Wi-Fi sources such as radio controlled doors, alarm systems, microwave ovens, lighting fixtures etc.

Wi-Fi 6 is just a label for the new technology. As the source of interference is the environment, it can't reduce it as such. Other developments such as MIMO help to alleviate the effect of interference.

Whether or not 40MHz channels are usable in your environment depends entirely on the environment. If 2.4GHz / 40MHz provides the best performance in your environment, nothing is preventing you from using it. You can use a Wi-Fi analyzer such as [inSSIDer](https://www.metageek.com/inssider/) to see how congested your environment is, and plan your channel usage accordingly.

Comment: Entirely empirically, and unscientifically -  moving to wifi 6 *did* seem to have less interference and significantly better range from my previous APs. I do run fully wifi capable 6 hardware at the moment, and it might be different for a wifi6 capable client

Comment: Heh ... it still doesn't reduce the amount of environmental interference, it just uses newer technologies to make it more robust so it's not as much affected :-)

Comment: When we were configuring a bunch of old b/g/n APs for indoor use a few years ago and couldn't connect to them at first, it took a while for us to figure out that their "40 MHz" option wasn't standard 20+20 MHz, but rather an Atheros proprietary "Turbo" mode that _was_ just straight up 40 MHz...

Comment: That must've been a long-lived experiment on Atheros side... didn't the 20+20 get standardized somewhere around that time?